# Return 2D array of chars with toString method (maze)

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, char, tostring

EDIT: SOLVED

I have some trouble with an assignment. We're supposed to read mazes from files (and solve them, but not the issue now), but I need a toString method to return the maze ready for printing. I can't figure out how to print it correctly.
Also, sorry for everything being in norwegian, we have to. Thanks for any help!

Some class context: I have a class Labyrint (maze), an abstract class Rute (box). Rute has two sub classes, SortRute (black box) and HvitRute (white box), and HvitRute's sub class Aapning (opening). The black box is recognized as the char '#', and white '.'. The box classes have a method char tilTegn() which returns either '#' or '.' if that's useful.

An example maze, 8 is columns and 9 is rows:

```
8 9
#####.###
#.....#.#
#.#####.#
#.#.....#
#.#.###.#
#.#.#.#.#
#.....#.#
#########
```

Thanks!

Comment: That is the problem with printing that you are having?

Comment: I have to return the maze looking like the example maze, so that I can print it via the main program, but I cannot get it to print correctly because there's something wrong with my toString method that I can't figure out.

Comment: How do you initialize `labyrint` from `lab` in the constructor, and what does the `toString` method of `Rute` look like? If you could update your questions with these details I'm sure someone would be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding to the String s using the `+` operator, consider creating a StringBuilder, or use the String.concat() method to concatenate strings. We don't add to Strings like we do in primitive types.

Replace `s += labyrint[i][j];` with `s.concat(labyrint[i][j];)`

Comment: Based on our curriculum there should be a way without StringBuilder and s.concat which we haven't learned about. I tried s.concat but it didn't work because Rute cannot be converted to String (Rute is the abstract class mentioned above).